# mysqli- php Select rows with >3 consecutive same valued fields

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select **book_no** of rows with 3 or more consecutive **DUE**s but so far   I have not been able to do it.

```
This is the table:

| book_no | name | mobile | date1 | date2 | date3 | date4 | date5 |
|---------|------|--------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|    1    | Cell |        | PAID  | DUE   | DUE   |       |       |
|    2    | Cell |        | PAID  | PAID  | PAID  |       |       | 
|    3    | Cell |        | DUE   | DUE   | DUE   | DUE   |       |
|    4    | Cell |        | PAID  | PAID  | PAID  |       |       | 
|    5    | Cell |        | DUE   | DUE   | DUE   |       |       |
```

So the query should return rows with book_no's **3,5**

***Please Help***

Comment: can you show us what you have tried

Comment: @depperm I have been thinking and havnt been table to come up with any solution which would enable me to count number of same field values in a row(i.e DUE). I cant figure out how to use SELECT for this condition

Comment: You're going to have a hard time doing this without normalizing the dates using potentially a join table. I'm assuming that the dates could go farther than `date5`? Is that correct?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go through each possibility or 'DUE' being in 3 columns, not the shortest query but it works, [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f475/8/0)

```
SELECT book_no FROM books WHERE
(date1 = 'DUE' AND date2 = 'DUE' AND date3 = 'DUE') OR
(date2 = 'DUE' AND date3 = 'DUE' AND date4 = 'DUE') OR
(date3 = 'DUE' AND date4 = 'DUE' AND date5 = 'DUE') OR
(date1 = 'DUE' AND date3 = 'DUE' AND date4 = 'DUE') OR
(date1 = 'DUE' AND date4 = 'DUE' AND date5 = 'DUE') OR
(date2 = 'DUE' AND date4 = 'DUE' AND date5 = 'DUE') OR
(date1 = 'DUE' AND date2 = 'DUE' AND date4 = 'DUE') OR
(date1 = 'DUE' AND date2 = 'DUE' AND date5 = 'DUE') OR
(date2 = 'DUE' AND date3 = 'DUE' AND date5 = 'DUE') OR
(date1 = 'DUE' AND date3 = 'DUE' AND date5 = 'DUE');
```

Comment: number of date[1-n] column depends upon the users input. Itl be very hard to implement your method. i'l give it atry

Comment: the number of sql columns depends on user input, don't you have a schema? If the number of columns depends on user input I might recommend mongo or a better way of storing the data

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it worked!

```
//get number of rows in the table
    $sql2="SELECT book_no FROM asaa ORDER BY book_no";
    if ($result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2))
      {
        // Return the number of rows in result set
        $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result2);
        printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result2);
      }

        $i=1;

        while($i<=$rowcount)
        {
                $bookNo=$i;
                $dueCount= 0;
                $sql = "SELECT *  FROM" .$tempTable. "WHERE book_no = " .$bookNo ;
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                if(!$result)
                {
                    echo "Error fetching data from tempTable: " . mysqli_error($conn);
              }
                else
                {
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {

                    foreach($row as $key => $var)
                    {
                        if($var=='DUE')
                        {
                            $dueCount++;
                            if($dueCount>2)
                                {
                                            //print users and dues with duecount>2
                                            echo "bookno $i has $dueCount dues"."<br>";
                                }
                        }
                }

            }
            $i++;
            }
        }
```